# Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa

I'm trying to allow my Pi to connect to a public Wifi network with no password, but I can't seem to get the wpa_supplicant.conf file right. Here's the file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

# Public network
network={
    ssid="PublicSSID"
    key_mgmt=None
}
```

When I try to connect, however, I get this error:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_cli daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
```

I am able to connect to my home networks and others that have passwords just fine. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Btw, I am connecting like this: (wifi is wlan1):

```
$ sudo ifdown wlan1
$ sleep 5
$ sudo ifup wlan1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your `network` block for a password-less network.  I snagged it from [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=38955#p321260):

```
network={
    ssid="YOUR NETWORK SSID"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
```